# no Thumbnai how to use RoboSpice ui Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, robospice

1、 I try RoboSpice demo project:robospice-sample-ui-spicelist
and try to write a application connection with my server side program.
but I got some error from android logcat as follows:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.octo.android.robospice.spicelist.SpiceArrayAdapter$ThumbnailAsynTask.doInBackground(SpiceArrayAdapter.java:327)
>   at com.octo.android.robospice.spicelist.SpiceArrayAdapter$ThumbnailAsynTask.doInBackground(SpiceArrayAdapter.java:310)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>   ... 4 more

my question is

1、 if I dont need Thumbnail which robospice ArrayAdapter I should choice?

2、 if I just use Listview by myself,dont use robospice ui listview, can give me some example?
because I fell , if server have 1000 record, android listview just got 1000 record at once is bad solution. listview have paging? and how server side codeing?

Comment: RS is open source, look at its source code, find what's goind wrong more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not running the latest version of RS. It's very difficult to find what is going wrong.